# Returning an attributes in specific order based on number of related attributes in DataMapper, Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

Sorry about that title, wasn't too sure how I could word it.

In a sinatra web app using datamapper, I am returning an array of instances of a model (named Polls) like so:

```
user.new_polls.to_json(:relationships => {:options => {:methods => [:votes]}})
```

Each Poll has many Options, each option has many Votes.

How would I be able to return the options in its respective poll, in order of descending votes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method in your `Poll` model, called `options_sorted_by_votes` (or something similar) and then use

```
user.new_polls.to_json(:relationships => {:options_sorted_by_votes => {:methods => [:votes]}})
```